# React Native Switch not animating when using React Navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am trying to add a [`Switch`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch) to my App, and its animation is not working. I tried to create a Snack and noticed that it works without navigation ([see this snack](https://snack.expo.io/@rafatcb/switch-animation-without-navigation)) but doesn't work when it is inside a Screen ([see this snack](https://snack.expo.io/@rafatcb/switch-animation-bug-with-navigation)).

It seems to be a problem just in Android.

The Switch code is just it:

```js
const MySwitch = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(false);
  return <Switch value={value} onValueChange={setValue} />;
};
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a problem with Expo, React Navigation or Switch?

In the worst case, how can I animate the component on my own?

---

Current behavior / Expected behavior:

[image]
[image]

React Navigation versions:

```js
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.2",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.7.2",
```

Answer (score 2):

came upon this bug as well, exactly as described.
I implement a settings page where if you toggle one option, another toggle option is displayed. The second Toggle does not suffer from this bug, and this is 100% consistent. So my guess is that he bug is triggered only for Switch components that are rendered on the initial render pass somehow.

as a workaround for this bug, introducing a small delay of 10ms for rendering Switch completely resolves the issue without visible side effects.

```js
function useDelay(ms: number) {
    const [gate, setGate] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setGate(true);
      }, ms);
    });
    return gate;
}

const delayRender = useDelay(10);

return (
      <>
        {delayRender && (
            <Switch />
        )}
      </>
);
```